# Parameterization cylinder under a plane

Tags: area, surfaces, parametrization

I have to evaluate the surface area of the cylinder
$$x^2+y^2=4$$
between the planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=2$. I was trying to use the following formula to area
$$\iint_{D}|\sigma_{\theta}\times\sigma_{z}|dA$$
where $\sigma(\theta,z)$ is its parameterization.

My doubt is: may I write $\sigma$ as follows?
$$\sigma(\theta,z)=(2\cos\theta,2\sin\theta,z)$$
with $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ and $0\leq z\leq2-2\cos\theta-2\sin\theta$.

Comment: What is your doubt here? Is $\sigma(\theta, z)$ on the cylinder? Is every point on the cylinder expressible as $\sigma(\theta, z)$ for some $\theta, z$ (and only by one value of $\theta, z$, except at the boundaries)? If you can answer those questions positively, then what other problem are you imagining? And if you cannot answer them positively, why not? What issue are you actually having?